# Why am I getting could not find or load main class error?

Tags: java

I am trying to run this piece of code

```
import java.io.*;

class Palindrome{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n, temp, rev=0;
        System.out.print("Input a number--> ");
        n = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
        temp = n;
        while(temp != 0){
            rev = rev*10 + temp%10;
            temp /= 10;
        }
        if( n == temp)
            System.out.println(n + " is a palindrome.");
          else
             System.out.println(n + " is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

I name the file palindrome.java.
The file compiles easily using without showing any error

```
javac palindrome.java
```

but when I run

```
java Palindrome.class
```

It shows

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Palindrome.class
```

The result of `ls` in my working directory is:

```
Palindrome.class  palindrome.java
```

Comment: and  dont use a default package!

Comment: run code using `java Palindrome` and not `java Palindrome.class`

Comment: Also note that Java is case-sensitive, so `palindrome` is not the same as `Palindrome`. Type the name **exactly**, using correct upper- and lower-case characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run using

```
java Palindrome
```

and not

```
java Palindrome.class
```